# How to catch ALL hardware keys of a PDA with Windows Mobile 6.1 - Compact Framework?

Tags: c#, keyboard, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm developping a Windows Mobile application for my PDA using the Compact Framework 3.5. I have a `Form` and I need to catch **all** the hardware keys of this PDA:

[image]

So, if I press a number button, the "Send" button, or the "Camera" button  I want to know which button was pressed.

I tried using the `KeyDown` end `KeyUp` event of my `Form`, but not all keys are intercepted. I tried also to PInvoke the `AllKeys` API, but in this way I can disable/enable all key excepts the camera key, and this is not what I want.

I need the complete control of my hardware keys.
How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can catch all keys that produce keyboard messages: http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2012/09/20/windows-mobile-cf-how-to-catch-f1-and-f2-in-weh/

If a key does not issue a keyboard message (like for example the scan button on Intermec issues a named event) you cannot catch it. Possibly the OEM provides an SDK for these keys too.

See also http://www.hjgode.de/wp/2011/12/20/windows-mobile-the-no-go-world-of-function-keys/

Answer (score 0):

To catch everything, you should use the SDK provided by the device manufacturer.

As you have found, `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` will only catch items that are connected to the Windows operating system.

Camera, Barcode Scanning, and Power Buttons are not items typically found electronic devices running Windows, and I do not believe there is an industry standard key assignment for those.